# JavaScript Set value in object

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new in JS  and something weird happen to me.
I try to set different value in an object and all the value of the table are changed
It appears the problems come from the creation of the object via a the object call "materialStd"

Value `obj.line[0].material.flow` of should stay at 123 instead of 3

Is someone able to explain what is happening there Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/vx6fno9p/5/

```js
var materialStd = {
  flow: 123,
  name: 'Raoul'
};
var obj = {
  id: 0,
  line: [{
      id: 1,
      material: materialStd
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      material: materialStd
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      material: materialStd
    }
  ]
}

testerror();

function testerror() {
  console.info(obj);
  //On appel une fct test

  console.log('' + obj.line[0].material.flow);
  console.log('' + obj.line[1].material.flow);
  console.log('' + obj.line[2].material.flow);

  test(obj);

  console.log('' + obj.line[0].material.flow);
  console.log('' + obj.line[1].material.flow);
  console.log('' + obj.line[2].material.flow);

}

function test(objetTraiter) {
  //  objetTraiter.line[0].material.flow=1;
  // objetTraiter.line[1].material.flow=2;
  objetTraiter.line[2].material.flow = 3;
  console.log('' + objetTraiter.line[0].material.flow);
  console.log('' + objetTraiter.line[1].material.flow);
  console.log('' + objetTraiter.line[2].material.flow);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is about **reference**, when you write :

```
line: [
    {id:1, material:materialStd},
    {id:2, material:materialStd},
    {id:3, material:materialStd}
]
```

The **same** object is put at the 3 places. So when you do `objetTraiter.line[2].material.flow=3`, it changes the object which is present in the 3 line objects.

**In Javascript**, to **clone data object** without keeping the same reference, we can use 
`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`. ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript))

So you could use :

```
line: [
    {id:1, material: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(materialStd))},
    {id:2, material: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(materialStd))},
    {id:3, material: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(materialStd))}
]
```

Comment: As `materialStd` only contains primitive types, you can use the spread operator instead of parsing, as it is slightly faster. `{id:1, material: {...materialStd} },`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `material: materialStd`, you are not getting a copy of the object `materialStd`, just a reference.

so when you update here `objetTraiter.line[2].material.flow=3;`

this actually changes the `materialStd` object, because `objetTraiter.line[2].material` has the reference to `materialStd` and not an independent object.

You must clone the object for you requirement.
There are multiple ways to clone the object, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` is one of it.

see [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object) for more info on object cloning.

You may find your desired results in below example

```js
var materialStd = {
  flow: 123,
  name: 'Raoul'
};

function cloneObject(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
}

var obj = {
  id: 0,
  line: [{
      id: 1,
      material: cloneObject(materialStd)  // clones
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      material: cloneObject(materialStd)
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      material: cloneObject(materialStd)
    }
  ]
}

testerror();

function testerror() {
  console.info(obj);
  //On appel une fct test

  console.log('' + obj.line[0].material.flow);
  console.log('' + obj.line[1].material.flow);
  console.log('' + obj.line[2].material.flow);

  test(obj);

  console.log('' + obj.line[0].material.flow);
  console.log('' + obj.line[1].material.flow);
  console.log('' + obj.line[2].material.flow);

}

function test(objetTraiter) {
  //  objetTraiter.line[0].material.flow=1;
  // objetTraiter.line[1].material.flow=2;
  objetTraiter.line[2].material.flow = 3;
  console.log('' + objetTraiter.line[0].material.flow);
  console.log('' + objetTraiter.line[1].material.flow);
  console.log('' + objetTraiter.line[2].material.flow);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Because pass by reference](https://medium.com/nodesimplified/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c).

```js
    var materialStd={flow:123, name:'Raoul'};
    var obj={
    id:0,
    line:[
      {id:1, material:materialStd},
      {id:2, material:materialStd},
      {id:3, material:materialStd}]
    }
    // Compare them
    console.log(
      (obj.line[0].material === obj.line[1].material)
      &&
      (obj.line[1].material === obj.line[2].material)
    ) // true
```

As suggested by other answers, clone a fresh reference for your intended behaviour inside **obj.line[index]["material"]**